# unresolved external symbol __imp_glewInit referenced in function main

Tags: c++, opengl

so i'm getting an error with my linker, and i'm been trying to figure this out. But i'm failing, can anyone help me this is the error that is appearing
unresolved external symbol __imp_glewInit referenced in function main

glew32.dll added

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        cout << "error" << endl;

    }
    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(0.1f, -0.1f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(-0.0f, -0.0f);

        glEnd();

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't solve the issue, but `glewInit` has to be done after `glfwMakeContextCurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

hey i figured out the issue, the issue was when defining `GLEW_STATIC` i forgot to add a ; in preprocessor section

Comment: Then you won't need `glew32.dll` I guess?